# Handling multiple windows in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

After clicking the submit button in my application, there will be three windows opened with title as claims, group benefits and controller. By default, the control is in the claims window. I wanted the control to be moved to group benefits window. To do that, i have used windows_handles function to find the number of windows opened so that i can loop it through to find the exact window to which i want to navigate to. However, the script returns only one window as opened, when there are three windows opened upon clicking the submit button. May i know why the script is returning only one window as opened, when the script have opened 3 windows actually please?

```
import selenium
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = 
webdriver.Ie("c:\\Users\\n0317311\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe")
time.sleep(3)

driver.get("https://test-groupmarkets.lmig.com/LMAuth/gms1nxtlogin.fcc")
time.sleep(3)
uname = driver.find_element_by_name("USER")
uname.send_keys("USERNAME")

upwd = driver.find_element_by_name("PASSWORD")
upwd.send_keys("Password")

uname.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(2)

windows = driver.window_handles
number_of_windows = len(windows)
print ("number of windows opened:", number_of_windows)
```

After running the above code, i am expecting the number of windows to be printed as 3 instead of 1, because the code has opened 3 windows upon clicking the submit button.

Comment: My guess is that it's taking a second or two for all three windows to open. Have you tried adding a wait for all windows to open?

Comment: There are 3 tabs opened in the same Browser?

Comment: Not three tabs. 3 different windows opened instead.. All 3 different windows are opened in IE browser.

Comment: @JeffC all the three windows opened instantaneously after clicking the submit button. So, i had applied a wait of 10 seconds, for all the 3 windows to open, after hitting the submit button. However, the windows_handles functions retrieves a value of 1, even though the number of windows opened at that moment are 3.